# How to get Optaplanner to select anchor as previousStandstill

Tags: java, optaplanner

we are using OptaPlanner for a optimization task similar to the vehicle routing example problem (see https://docs.optaplanner.org/6.5.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#vehicleRouting), but much more complex with a lot more domain knowledge.

Now we have a specific use case where a *Vehicle*(=anchor of *previousStandstill* / *nextCustomer* chain) is new to the planning problem and should get quickly assigned one of e.g. 500 *Customers*.
Therefore I would like to use a custom *SwapMoveSelectorConfig* like this:

```
    public class VehicleSelectionFilter implements SelectionFilter<Standstill> {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(ScoreDirector scoreDirector, Standstill selection) {
            return selection instanceof Vehicle;
        }
    }

    EntitySelectorConfig esc = new EntitySelectorConfig(Standstill.class);
    List<java.lang.Class<? extends SelectionFilter>> selectionFilterClassList = new ArrayList<>();

    selectionFilterClassList.add(VehicleSelectionFilter.class);
    esc.setFilterClassList(selectionFilterClassList);

    SwapMoveSelectorConfig anchorSwapMoveSelectorConfig = new SwapMoveSelectorConfig();
    anchorSwapMoveSelectorConfig.setEntitySelectorConfig(new EntitySelectorConfig(Customer.class));
    anchorSwapMoveSelectorConfig.setVariableNameIncludeList(Collections.singletonList("previousStandstill"));
    anchorSwapMoveSelectorConfig.setSecondaryEntitySelectorConfig(esc);
    moveSelectorConfigList.add(anchorSwapMoveSelectorConfig);
```

However, this is not a valid constellation due to the different *EntitySelector* classes (*Standstill* and *Customer*):

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The entitySelector (EntitySelectorConfig(class org.optaplanner.examples.vehiclerouting.domain.Customer))'s entityDescriptor (EntityDescriptor(org.optaplanner.examples.vehiclerouting.domain.Customer)) and secondaryEntitySelectorConfig (EntitySelectorConfig(interface org.optaplanner.examples.vehiclerouting.domain.Standstill))'s entityDescriptor (EntityDescriptor(org.optaplanner.examples.vehiclerouting.domain.Standstill)) must have the same entity class.`

If I take the same base class *Standstill*, I cannot access the non-existing member variable *previousStandstill*.
*nextCustomer* also cannot be assigned via `anchorSwapMoveSelectorConfig.setVariableNameIncludeList(Collections.singletonList("nextCustomer"));`
due to only being an inverse relation shadow variable.

How can I achieve the desired selectorConfig to force OptaPlanner to try to assign *Customers* to *Vehicles* as *nextCustomer*?

(The general case would be: How to assign a non-anchor planning entity directly to/after an anchor?)

Comment: With a "custom move" (see docs) you can probably do this too, maybe a custom MoveIteratorFactory is enough and reuse ChainedSwapMove or ChainedChangeMove for the move itself.

Comment: I managed to get it working, a custom MoveIteratorFactory does not suffice (because the ValueSelector does not choose the correct anchor values somehow) - I needed a custom Move, a custom MoveIterator, a custom MoveSelector (and a custom MoveSelectorConfig) as well as a custom SelectionFilter, most of them only to pass the anchor EntitySelector along for the custom move.
However, I would have assumed there is an easier/more direct approach. I will also recommend this as a feature request because of the real-world use case.

Comment: To recommend this as a feature, please [create a jira](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER) with use case description and some code to illustrate the problem. Please summarize it and make it concrete.

Comment: It's very strange that a custom Move with a custom MoveIteratorFactory doesn't suffice. If you use AnchorShadowVariable, then your planning entities know the anchor, so your custom move can just pick it from the entity.

Comment: Yes, each planning entity knows its anchor, but I need to get the anchor that has no nextCustomer assigned, so I cannot use the anchor shadow variable of a customer that I get via customerEntitySelector

Comment: Interesting - thanks for explaining - do create that jira. I guess you could use a custom shadow variable that keeps track of all empty anchors to avoid having to write your own MoveSelector (something that's not really intended ;) but that will probably just dirty your domain model I guess?

Comment: Feature request created: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER-839